# Error in parsing django variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, django

I have a django app. I am using the below code to use access a django variable in javascript.

```
var pd_info = {{pd_inf|safe}};
```

In Firefox, this is giving Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ] after element list note: [ opened at line 327, column 15. Chrome gives Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string

Debugger displays

```
var ad_info = [[15.0, 1, 100000000.0, u'PHD', 5.0]];
```

The variable works perfectly fine in django template. The javascript was also working before (but could be hacked)

How to resolve this?

Comment: just a guess, because you have not provided any detail really, would be to close the opening `[` to fix your syntax error?

Comment: what does the template filter output? View source to check your generated javascript - this should give away what's going on and how to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
var pd_info = {{pd_inf|safe}};
```

To this:

```
var pd_info = "{{pd_inf|safe}}";
```

You can then type convert with js as needed.

In views.py you can convert the object to a string like so:

```
def my_view_function(request):

    ...

    my_var = json.dumps(my_var)

    return render(request, 'template.html', context={'my_var' : my_var})
```

Comment: It gives Uncaught SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier when the variable contains double quotes.                                                                                                                       var cd_info = "[[1, 1, u'1234567890', u'atkral11@gmail.com', u"amit's kingdom", 66.0, 66.0]]";

Comment: Try sensing the variable in as a string instead of an object - see my updated answer.

Comment: Try sending* the variable

Comment: The simple way used to work fine till now. I suspect it was hacked.to force an error.. But I really don't have a choice. I just need to test other components of the page. Whatever works for now is fine with me. can handle the hacking later.